# ICSharp text editor for Mono

Tags: text, mono, editor, monodevelop, icsharpcode

I know there is a text-editing control which was built for MonoDevelop, but where exactly is it? In the AddIns and bin folder of MonoDevelop in Program Files after installation, there a bunch of DLL files but none of them contain any controls which I can drag into the MSVC designer.

Where is the Mono text-editing control? The reason I am asking is because the standard ICSharp TextEditor calls a bunch of P/Invokes, and I have no idea how to get rid of those so alternatively if someone could help me with that I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you just re-post your question that was closed as off-topic yesterday?

Comment: I fail to see how it was off-topic. A similar question exists, but how come that wasn't closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for Mono.TextEditor.dll, but it is a Gtk# widget, not an MSVC control.

Comment: Makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks for the info.